# WebForms ScriptManager tag inaccessible in VB code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have an aspx page with this tag in the `<body>`:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server" />
```

Now elsewhere in the aspx page I have some VB code (embedded in the page using `<% %>`, not in a code behind vb file):

```
scriptManager1.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules_ContactType", tempStr)
```

Problem is, I get a compile error on that line saying that scriptManager1 is not declared. I thought all controls with `runat="server"` are accessible in code? Why is this not working?

edit:

Oh, I figured it out - sort of. `RegisterClientScriptBlock` is a shared method of `ScriptManager` for some reason, so I need to call it like so:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules_ContactType", tempStr)
```

Calling it as an instance method won't work.

However - now I am getting an error saying that the ScriptManager class itself doesn't exist! I am referencing the appropriate namespace like so at the top of the page:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %>
```

Why is ScriptManager not being found? I even get an error if I explicitly reference the class by namespace:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules_ContactType", tempStr)
```

edit: here is a simple page which should reproduce the error:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FRED</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <%
            System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules_ContactType", "alert('fred');")
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

edit: tried this as suggested, same error:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules_ContactType", "alert('fred');")
    End Sub
</script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FRED</title>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the arguments you are trying to use in the method call, it looks a bit like you are mixing up two separate classes:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager
```

[System.Web.UI.ScriptManager docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager?view=netframework-4.8)

and

```
System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager
```

[System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager?view=netframework-4.8)

The first one of these two lives in the `System.Web.Extensions.dll` assembly. Have you checked that you are referencing this assembly?

The second one is exposed through the `ClientScript` property on the `Page` class. I think what you *should* be doing is this (note C# syntax, should be easy to change to VB though):

```
<%
    this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules_ContactType", "alert('fred');");
%>
```

Comment: I am referencing `System.Web.UI`. What's the difference between these two classes? Why do they both exist?

Comment: @ekolis `System.Web.UI` is a namespace, and you are importing it. But several assemblies (~ dll files)  can contribute to the same namespace. The `System.Web.UI.ScriptManager` class is added to the namespace from the `System.Web.Extensions.dll` assembly. In order to use it in your project, you have to add a reference to the assembly in Visual Studio.

Comment: @ekolis You asked *Why do they both exist?*. I don't really know, but it's a fact that they both *do exist*. So when trying to use one of them, you need to know which one and call the methods with the correct arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example here, it looks like you may need to call it in Page_PreRender - the example is in C# rather than VB but the premise should be the same.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Nope, tried that, I still get the same error. Thanks though!

Comment: Ok one other thought, this is a long shot, but make sure you have System.Web as a reference at the project level.  One time recently I ran into a case where I couldn't access something in an assembly unless I've explicitly included that assembly as a reference.

Comment: Also, what version of .net are you using? I was going to try to replicate with your simple page, but when I copy your code in, VS tells me that registerclientscriptblock has the wrong number of parameters.

Comment: `System.Web` is referenced in my project. I am using .NET Framework version 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

I took your sample with the call in Page_PreRender and with a few adjustments (different parameters for RegisterClientScriptBlock, putting a form with runat=server around the script manager) I was able to get it to work for me.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(scriptManager1, Me.GetType(), "mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules_ContactType", "alert('fred');", True)
    End Sub
</script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FRED</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure why your parameters for RegisterClientScriptBlock were different though, so I'm wondering if there's a difference in .NET version? Still, hopefully this helps.

Comment: I tried putting the `ScriptManager` in a `form` tag, but I still get compile errors saying that it is undefined when I try to pass it in to `RegisterClientScriptBlock` (and `System.Web.UI.ScriptManager` still can't be found...)

Comment: You can copy the exact code I just gave you and it doesn't work for you? I tried that exact code on 4.6.1 and it still worked fine for me. If that exact code still doesn't work then there must be something else going on, but if that sample works for you and your actual code still doesn't, then you need to look at where the differences are between the two.